# Uploading Secret Shares of files to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, byte, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to split a file into pieces and then upload each of the shares into a blob storage, this is the code i have so far.

```
                [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        int n = 5, t = 3;
        RandomSources r = RandomSources.SHA1;
        Encryptors e = Encryptors.ChaCha20;
        Algorithms a = Algorithms.CSS;
        if (image.ContentLength > 0)

        {
            Facade f = new Facade(n, t, r, e, a);
            Byte[] bytes = ObjectToByteArray(image.InputStream);
            Share[] shares = f.split(bytes);

            foreach (Share share in shares)
            {
                byte[] serialized = share.serialize();
            }

            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(image.FileName);

                 blob.UploadFromByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                blob.UploadFromStream(serialized);

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Upload");
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to alter this as when i try and use the upload form it just doesnt work and doesnt produce any errors.

Comment: Does it work if you upload a single file?

Comment: I can't understand your code actually. 1. I don't think variable "serialized" can be accessed out of the foreach scope, does your code really compile? 2. What do you want to upload to Azure Blob storage, bytes or serialized? If you call both UploadFromByteArray() and UploadFromStream(), the latter one will always overwrite the prior one. 3. As I can see "serialized" is a byte array, I don't think it can be passed into UploadFromStream().